# How to know what part of code uses Glibc

Tags: c++, linux, glibc

I have an app, this app uses Glibc, but i want to compile without linking glibc and i need to remove/change code which uses it. Where can i get list of functions defined in glibc?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just take `glibc` off the link line and see where all of the undefined symbol errors show up?

Comment: Almost _everything_ except the most basic program without any input or output needs the standard library. Why would you want to link without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need glibc to provide the startup for your typical `main` entry point (such as setting up the `argc`, `argv` into the right places).

You need glibc to call system calls (it provides the "wrappers" around `read`, `write`, `open`, `fork`, etc.

You need glibc to provide I/O functions such as `printf`, `scanf`, `getchar`, `getc`, `fopen`, `fclose`,etc.

You need glibc to provide typical string functions, such as `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strtok`, `strchr`, etc.

You need glibc to provide other standard functions, `rand`, `srand`, `qsort`, `assert`, `exit`, `setjmp`, `longjmp`, etc.

In summary, you probably can't write any meaningful program without glibc.

Unless of course, you replace glibc with some other library that provides the same functionality. There [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) which is supposedly a bit more "lightweight", as it targets embedded systems, where memory is a little more at a premium.